# Можно ли с помощью JavaScript открыть вкладку в браузере, взять из её HTML данные и вернуть их на первую вкладку?

Tags: javascript

Положим, что всплывающие окна на сайте НЕ блочатся. 
P.S. Считаю важным также отметить, что домен один и тот же. То есть нужно взять инфу с ЭТОГО ЖЕ сайта.

Comment: Обязательно таким способом? Если нет используйте AJAX.

Comment: Да, обязательно, ибо сайт не мой, я лишь пишу скрипт для работы с одним порталом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Черновик функции для решения вашей задачи нужным для вас способом:

```
function loadContent(link, callback) {
    var tab = window.open(link);
    tab.onload = function() {
        callback(tab.document.body.innerHTML);
        tab.close();
    };
}
```

Пример вызова

```
loadContent('https://ya.ru/', function(text) {
   console.log(text);
});
```

Однако, правильно решать подобные задачи с помощью AJAX-запросов.

Comment: Согласен, однако сервер и сайт не мой - мне нужна лишь инфа для скрипта и опыт.